# How can I center an html element in an email template for email clients like Outlook if it is less than 100% width?

Tags: html, css, email, cross-browser

I have a table that is only about 400px wide and the email template is 600px. I need to center this with nothing but padding or margin on the sides. I would normally just use margin:0 auto; but this doesn't work in all email clients, especially Outlook.

Comment: Is your table at fixed with?

Comment: Yeah, or at least a max width until it gets to phone size.

Comment: And you're looking to center the template or the table?

Comment: Just center the table within the wider template.

Comment: If your table is 400px wide and your template 600px, can't you just put a 100px horizontal margin?

Comment: I can't remember if that works on Outlook or not. I know it has lots of issues with margins and padding. It might work. I also tried setting the table to display: inline-block; and text-aligh: center; the outer container.

Comment: Guess I won't be of any help here. I haven't got any experience in that kind of html. Good luck!